# Copying files through an SSH Proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer, scp

I want to copy some files from remote machine at work, but I can't ssh to the machine directly,

I login via an SSH proxy which presents menu of hosts to connect too, I choose the machine I want and then login with my password.

Is there a way with SCP or SSH or some other means to be able to copy files from the remote to my local host?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both hops use SSH, you can use port forwarding to tunnel SSH inside of the outside hop's SSH and access the internal network directly.

```
Host MAKESOCKS.internal-network
HostName ssh-gate.internal-network
DynamicForward localhost:10022

Host *.internal-network
ProxyCommand connect -S 127.0.0.1:10022 %h %p
```

Use it like this:

```
ssh -f -N MAKESOCKS.internal-network
ssh host.internal-network
```

The `connect` command is in the `connect-proxy` package on Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your remote host is called example.com, you can setup a 'master' ssh connection like so

```
ssh -Mt -S /tmp/ssh user@example.com
```

Then you can piggy back your scp over this like so

```
scp -o "ControlPath /tmp/ssh" <src_file> user@example.com:/<target_file>
```

**Edit** : Ah. I didn't read your question properly. You were connecting via a separate proxy. In that case, the port forwarding technique suggested in the other answer would be more appropriate.